# Writing XML with Linq: Token EndDocument in state Document would result in an invalid XML document

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

[Looks like more than it actually is]

I'm trying to write a small C# program that downloads the mails of a Mail-Account via IMAP. I have a List with E-Mail objects and a method which should return a valid XDocument populated with the data from the List. The XML should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Folder ID="0" name="INBOX">
    <Mail UID="328" fromAddress="serious.business@server.com" fromDisplayName="Business guy" toAddress="me@server.com" toDisplayName="David Onter">
        <Priority>High</Priority>
        <Subject>Important info!</Subject>
        <Content>The Content goes in here.</Content>
        <AttachmentPath>/Attachments/important_document.pdf</AttachmentPath>
    </Mail>
    <Mail UID="329" fromAddress="coolkid@server.com" fromDisplayName="The cool kid" toAddress="me@server.com" toDisplayName="David Onter">
        <Priority>Normal</Priority>
        <Subject>Waaazuuuuup</Subject>
        <Content>Stay fly and snazzy</Content>
        <AttachmentPath></AttachmentPath>
    </Mail>
</Folder>
<Folder ID="1" name="Archive">
    <Mail UID="420" fromAddress="dude@server.com" fromDisplayName="Classmate8" toAddress="me@server.com" toDisplayName="David Onter">
        <Priority>Normal</Priority>
        <Subject>Maths homework</Subject>
        <Content>What was maths hw?</Content>
        <AttachmentPath></AttachmentPath>
    </Mail>
</Folder>
```

---

This is the error it throws:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Token EndDocument in state Document would result in an invalid XML document.
at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.ThrowInvalidStateTransition(Token token, State currentState)
at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.AdvanceState(Token token)
at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteEndDocument()
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(String fileName, SaveOptions options)
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(String fileName)
at DownTheMail.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

---

```
// Export to xml
XDocument xmlDoc = MailToXML(emailList);
xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\Users\David\Documents\file.xml");
```

---

And this is the actual method:

```
private static XDocument MailToXML(List<Email> emailList) {
    XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-16", "yes"));
    // Compiler food, will be overwritten.
    XElement folder = new XElement("Folder");

    for(int i=0; i<emailList.Count; i++) {
        if(i!=0&&emailList[i-1].FolderId==emailList[i].FolderId) {
            // Write Mail and add it to the current folder
            folder.Add(new XElement("Mail", new XAttribute("UID", emailList[i].Uid),
                                            new XAttribute("fromAddress", emailList[i].FromAddress),
                                            new XAttribute("fromDisplayName", emailList[i].FromDisplayName),
                                            new XAttribute("ToAddresses", emailList[i].ToAddresses),
                                            new XAttribute("ToDisplayNames", emailList[i].ToDisplayNames),
                                                new XElement("Importance", emailList[i].Importance),
                                                new XElement("Subject", emailList[i].Subject),
                                                new XElement("BodyText", emailList[i].BodyText),
                                                new XElement("AttachmentPath", emailList[i].AttachmentPath)));
        } else {
            if(i!=0) {
                // Add current, finished folder to the document
                xmlDoc.Add(folder);
            }
            // Create new folder
            folder = new XElement("Folder", new XAttribute("id", emailList[i].FolderId),
                                            new XAttribute("name", emailList[i].FolderName));

            // Write Mail and add it to the newly created folder as the first element
            folder.Add(new XElement("Mail", new XAttribute("UID", emailList[i].Uid),
                                            new XAttribute("fromAddress", emailList[i].FromAddress),
                                            new XAttribute("fromDisplayName", emailList[i].FromDisplayName),
                                            new XAttribute("ToAddresses", emailList[i].ToAddresses),
                                            new XAttribute("ToDisplayNames", emailList[i].ToDisplayNames),
                                                new XElement("Importance", emailList[i].Importance),
                                                new XElement("Subject", emailList[i].Subject),
                                                new XElement("BodyText", emailList[i].BodyText),
                                                new XElement("AttachmentPath", emailList[i].AttachmentPath)));
        }
    }

    return xmlDoc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the Root element in your XML. The XML you provided is invalid. For e.g. adding root element to following XML would make it **Valid.** XML documents must contain one root element that is the parent of all other elements: From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element).

> Each XML document has exactly one single root element. It encloses all
>   the other elements and is therefore the sole parent element to all the
>   other elements. ROOT elements are also called PARENT elements.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<Folder ID="0" name="INBOX">
    <Mail UID="328" fromAddress="serious.business@server.com" fromDisplayName="Business guy" toAddress="me@server.com" toDisplayName="David Onter">
        <Priority>High</Priority>
        <Subject>Important info!</Subject>
        <Content>The Content goes in here.</Content>
        <AttachmentPath>/Attachments/important_document.pdf</AttachmentPath>
    </Mail>
    <Mail UID="329" fromAddress="coolkid@server.com" fromDisplayName="The cool kid" toAddress="me@server.com" toDisplayName="David Onter">
        <Priority>Normal</Priority>
        <Subject>Waaazuuuuup</Subject>
        <Content>Stay fly and snazzy</Content>
        <AttachmentPath></AttachmentPath>
    </Mail>
</Folder>
<Folder ID="1" name="Archive">
    <Mail UID="420" fromAddress="dude@server.com" fromDisplayName="Classmate8" toAddress="me@server.com" toDisplayName="David Onter">
        <Priority>Normal</Priority>
        <Subject>Maths homework</Subject>
        <Content>What was maths hw?</Content>
        <AttachmentPath></AttachmentPath>
    </Mail>
</Folder>
</root>`

Comment: And how would I add a root element? Defining a single new XElement at the top and adding everything to this new container in the loop and adding the Container to the document afterwards doesn't work. It only writes the Root element in the file this way, but not the previously added Sub-Elements.

Comment: Found the mistake, it never reached the xmlDoc.Add(folder); part in my loop.

Answer (score 1):

The resulting XML is definitely invalid as xml allows only one root element. In fact, XDocument class exposes "Root" property whose type is XElement. You can add your "folder" to this "Root" element instead of XDocument directly.

You can also initialize XDocument with simple xml string, not with XDeclaration.

Comment: Doesn't work, it's a Nullpointer. I guess I have to define the root first. But how would I add a root element? Defining a single new XElement at the top and adding everything to this new container in the loop and adding the container to the document afterwards doesn't work. It only writes the Root element in the file this way, but not the previously added Sub-Elements of it.

Comment: Found the mistake, it never reached the xmlDoc.Add(folder); part in my loop.